# Increase utilization of GPU for Sentence Transformer inference

Tags: python, nlp, gpu, bert-language-model

We'are using a Sentence Transformer model to calculate 1024-dim vectors for the purpose of similarity search. The model is served by a FastAPI web server exposing an API for other services to request a vector for a given text.

So we are planning to calculate vectors for a large document set (about 10_000_000 documents) and are running some tests.

- Using a CPU, we're getting encoding speed of about 0.1 second per a sentence.
- Using a GTX 1650 card we're getting about 0.01 second per a sentence with an average GPU  utilization of about 50-60%

So we decided to see if we could get further improvements by renting out a VPS with Tesla T4 card. The results are somewhat disappointing:

- We're still getting the same 0.01 seconds per one sentence but with average GPU utilization of only 10-15%. So it looks like the card is heavily under-utilized.

We tried increasing the number of workers, but it did not have any effect.

What can I do to improve utilization of the GPU and get faster performance.

The embeddings are calculated using this line of code:

```py
model.encode(text, device='cuda', normalize_embeddings=True).tolist()
```

I'm using this command to monitor GPU performance

```
watch -d -n 0.5 nvidia-smi
```

and watching this column `GPU-Util`

Comment: There are many variables at play so concrete answers may be difficult without more information. Generally, an underutilised GPU is a sign of IO limitations somewhere in the pipeline---be it hardware (CPU, RAM, GPU, storage) or software (FastAPI, the sentence transformer implementation itself, or the parameters you are using). I'd start by checking your system's hardware to see if any are at full utilization, if they are, that may be the bottleneck. If that doesn't seem to be the case, you'll need to look at optimizing your code (to the degree that is possible).